# What has happend to TeXShop [LaTeX] - shows only chinese characters

Tags: macos, latex, report

I really need help with this problem I've been having a while now. Every .tex file on my computer is like this.. (as seen on the image) I have no idea how to fix this please help. TeXShop shows the pdf file correct but i can't see my latex code.

Thanks guys!

Regards K.

[image]